# Change table data in 2nd table in same view upon selecting the row in 1st table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

I wanted to know how can we change the cell.textLabel.text of the second table, when we select the row of the first table.. P.S : Both the tables are in the same View..so i cant push another view controller to cover up the present view.

Example : I have some 10 rows of data in the first table, upon selecting 1st row in table 1 it should display "table1, row1 " or any other string.. in the first row of the second table., when I select 2nd row of first table.., the first row of the second table should now display as "table1,row2"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Try something likethis....    
Have a string NSString *str=[[NSString alloc]init];

    for the first table 


         didSelectRowAtindexPath
            {
            if(indexpath.row==1)
            str=@"1 row 1 table";
            if(indexpath.row==2)
            str=@"2 row 1 table");
            [table2 reloadData];
            }
        In table2
        cellforRowAtindexPath
        {
        cell.textLabel.text=str;
        }
```